# clear understanding of grep backreference

Tags: command-line, grep

```
grep '^\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\) .* \1$' myfile.txt
```

catches

```
abc whatever whatever abc
aaa whatever whatever aaa
```

I thought my `grep` would only catch the second line that start with "aaa" because `^\([[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)` only produces strings, such as `a | aa | aaa | b | bbbb`, not `ab | abc`.

How is it also outputting the first line as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capture group `\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)` captures a sequence of one or more alphabetic characters, and you anchored it to the start-of-line with `^`

So it will match `abc` in the first line, and `aaa` in the second line.

The whole expression `'^\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\) .* \1$` therefore matches any line of at least two space-separated sequences that ends with the same alphabetic sequence that it started with:

```
abc <anything - or nothing> abc
aaa <anything - or nothing> aaa
```

and so on.

Comment: isn't [[:alpha:]] the same as [a-z]? so [a-z]{1,} matches a, aa, b ,bbb, and so on, but not ab or abc. So I thought my capture group only captures a sequence of one or more same alphabetic characters.

Comment: @Mint.K regular expressions are not expansions - they don't "produce" anything

Comment: I meant they match.

Comment: Oh I guess "bc" in "abc" doesn't have anything to do with [[:alpha:]] as long as "a" is matched first, correct?

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` means any single alphabetic character;  `[[:alpha:]]{2}` means `[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]` i.e. any two alphabetic characters, and so on - this does **NOT** become the same as `aa` just because the first happened to match `a`

Comment: I thought it'd behave like ([[:alpha:]]){2} for some reason. I got it now. Thank you.